# Why is /mnt/hgfs not appearing?

Tags: windows, vmware, sharing

This might be a basic reason, but somehow I have not been able to achieve it.

I am running a guest Kubuntu OS on a windows one, and I am trying to share a folder between OSes. The VMware tools have been installed properly, VM -> Settings -> Options -> Share Folders is set properly, and my windows folder is shared.

Any idea what else could prevent the hgfs folder to appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution Copied from Peretz:

In a previous attempt, I installed open-vm-dkms. This was preventing the hgfs file to appear.

```
sudo apt-get purge open-vm-dkms
```

and reintalling vmware tools solved the conflict.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, the auto-installed VMWare tools didn't do the job, but Ubuntu has a tool called vmware-hgfsmounter, if I installed it then I could do this:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools  
sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs  
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

After running these commands, `/mnt/hgfs` should now contain your shares.

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/588304/no-mnt-hgfs-in-ubuntu-guest-under-vmware-fusion)

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to replace `vmhgfs` with `fuse.vmhgfs-fuse` on Ubuntu 18 / VMware Fusion 8.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 19 this worked (after changing the cdrom to IDE)

sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs
sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other